# NgxTranslate is not working with HTTP interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, translate, ngx-translate

I am using ngxtranslate to translate the application. It works like charm.
Problem is that I have HttpInterceptor which is trying to get data from local storage in the beginning and shows a dialog if asking you if you want to load the last changes or dismiss.
Problem is that text here in the dialog is not translated and I don't know how to do it because everywhere it works.
HTTPInterceptor file

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

        @Injectable()
        export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        
          constructor(private cacheService: HttpCacheService, private dialog: MatDialog, private translate: TranslateService) {}
        
          intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return from(this.handle(req, next));
          }
         .......
            const cachedResponse: HttpResponse<any> = 
             this.cacheService.get(reqId);
             if (cachedResponse) {
              console.log('cache hit');

              const dialogResult = await this.openDialog();
              if (dialogResult) {
              console.log('Loading item from cache');
              // return modifyied response
            .........
               async openDialog() {
                  const dialogData = new ConfirmationDialogModel(
                  await this.translate.instant('some.text'),
                  await this.translate.instant('some.anotherText')
               );
             ....
```

output is just `some.text` and `some.anotherText`
What can I do to make it work please?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `this.translate.instant` function (which returns a string not a promise) with `await`, which is not correct. You should either use the `instant` function without `await` or use `this.translate.get('xyz').toPromise()` function instead which returns an observable, then convert it to promise to be awaitable.

Answer (score -1):

do you try it ?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
openDialog()
return from(this.handle(req, next));
}
```

Comment: Sorry i cant do it like this I updated my answer where I am calling openDialog()